# Blender. How can i separate mesh / Edge

Tags: modeling

I was wondering if its possible to separate from a mesh inly The edges, as curves, só i can later transformar that "tube" in geometry.

Like in Max you can detach and choose The type of mesh, and if its a spline you can "mesh" it!

Thanks!!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes, it is possible to separate elements of Blender meshes into separate objects, and convert the elements into a mesh tube. Details of the workflow to accomplish this in blender may be somewhat different from the workflow needed to accomplish the same thing in Max, and might vary from one Blender object to another..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Object Mode* press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and select *Curve from Mesh/Text*. Then in the curve properties under *Fill* select *Full* and to give it depth under *Bevel* increase *Depth*. Also use *Resolution* to make it more round.

Comment: Nope, Like from a mesh i can separete the edges, perfect. Now i want to render that separated edges as tubes (square, round etc) Like this: In Blender: [Separated Edges] (http://imgur.com/a/b7JSl)  // And now on 3DsMax, the spline render option : [Spline] (http://imgur.com/a/Vx8tB)

Comment: Updated Answer.